# How can I store a variable value on my Raspbian Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a small python script and everything works well. However, when I switch off the value is reset to 0. I already tried to write to a .txt file and read it and load it on power up.
However, some times the file still loses information. Thus, I would like to know if there is an alternative.
Thank you!

Comment: The file is probably open when the pi is powered off, so it corrupts, but this is just a guess without any idea of what you're doing.

Comment: show your code.  Under what circumstances does the file not retain the data?